# Adding a variable to routeconfig ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, routetable

I am generating my `routeconfig` from a database.

I have a file `combine.aspx` which combines all data into a virtual webpage.

Right now the routing is working, however I have a problem.

I want the url to look like this:

```
www.domain.com/Home
```

This is working, however the combiner needs the `pageId`. How can I send this without showing it in the url? This is how the route is combined now:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
   page.pageName,
   url,
   "~/combine.aspx");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this overload of MapPageRoute: [RouteCollection.MapPageRoute Method (String, String, String, Boolean, RouteValueDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784594%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    page.pageName,
    url,
    "~/combine.aspx"
    false,
    new{ pageId = page.pageId }//or whatever variable value you want to use
);
```